# Dynamic Facebook Meta Tag Rendering using create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm currently working on an app that shares pictures on FB using create react app(not ejected). I'm having problems with sharing the url since the meta tags cannot be edited dynamically. The [user guide of CRA states](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#generating-dynamic-meta-tags-on-the-server) :

*read index.html into memory and replace **OG_TITLE**, **OG_DESCRIPTION***

I'm not that knowledgable yet on express, can someone guide me to the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: The documentation is asking you to host the output files in your server and then replace the strings inside index.html with your dynamic stuff on the fly. If you happen to use express to host the content, [this extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-static-transform/) may help.